# Construct dataframe with levels

Tags: r

I just migrated from Python to R and I would like to know if there is any function in R which is similar to pandas.MultiIndex.from_product?

Example:

```
letters <- c('a', 'b')
numbers <- c(1, 2, 3)
df <- somefunction(letters, numbers)
df
 letters numbers
1   a       1
2   a       2
3   a       3
4   b       1
5   b       2
6   b       3
```

Comment: How do you decide that `numbers` should be repeated twice ?

Comment: numbers should be repeated by the length of letters. I could write a small function to it but I wonder if there is any existing one in R.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes:

```
> letters <- c('a', 'b')
> numbers <- c(1, 2, 3)
> expand.grid(letters=letters, numbers=numbers)
  letters numbers
1       a       1
2       b       1
3       a       2
4       b       2
5       a       3
6       b       3
```

You can also use `CJ` from the `data.table` package. It is faster. But the result is not an ordinary dataframe, it is a datatable:

```
> library(data.table)
> CJ(letters=letters, numbers=numbers)
   letters numbers
1:       a       1
2:       a       2
3:       a       3
4:       b       1
5:       b       2
6:       b       3
```

Comment: expand.grid part is exactly the same as duplicated post, but data.table CJ is new, I would suggest to post CJ as answer on duplicated post, and delete this one?